# C#/MVC Windows Authentication still prompting for connection to server in which SQL database resides

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have my internal MVC application all setup with Windows Authentication.  We have added the internal domain to our Intranet Zone to allow the pass-through authentication, but we still get prompted for authentication to the server where the database resides.

I am no network admin by any means, but was curious how I can pass-through authentication to gain access to this DB.  At first I thought it was actual access the the DB itself, but that is not the case.  It is prompting for connection to that server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please copy paste your web.config? Especially the connection string.

Comment: Web.config is too long but below is my connection string.
`
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="InventoryEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Inventory.csdl|res://*/Models.Inventory.ssdl|res://*/Models.Inventory.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername\sqlexpress;initial catalog=DB.Web;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
`

It prompts for auth to "servername"

Comment: Gettig impersonation to work with SSPI (integrated security) is painful. Just so you know. It involves Service Principal Names. I tried for weeks to get it to work and then I gave up.

Comment: @user2008011 - do not add additional information in comments, edit your post to include it.

Comment: @user2008011 - it's impossible for your web browser to pop up a request for authentication for your database.  The connection is between your web browser and your web server.  The connection from your web server to the database is separate, and is impossible to forward in this manner.  If you're seeing a popup, it's because of the web server authentication, not your database authentication.